# Style Wordpress Custom Post Type Single Page

Tags: plugins, posts, single, customization

I'm registering a custom post type 'events'. The events can be listed using a shortcode, and when you click on an event you go to the single view of that event. Now, I want this single view page to be styled completely different using all of the event's metadata to create maps, images, etc, but I cannot figure out how. Using a template for this single view isn't an option since this is a plugin and should work with any theme. Just filtering the post's content isn't enough as I want to style the title too.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can filter the title also.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least 3 options to choose from:

You can use the single CPT file name which you can grab from the source code in the body classes or a custom class which can be added directly to the single-cpt.php file or using a functions file with conditional tag.

```
.single-cpt {
your declarations
}
```

Or add directly to single-cpt.php file

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpsites_cpt_body_class' );
function wpsites_cpt_body_class( $classes ) {
   $classes[] = 'your-single-cpt-class';
   return $classes;
}
```

Or with conditional in functions file

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpsites_cpt_body_class' );
    function wpsites_cpt_body_class( $classes ) {
if ( is_singular('your-cpt') ) {
       $classes[] = 'your-single-cpt-class';
       return $classes;
    }
}
```